# How to select '::cue' element with js selector & change it? I am trying to create a button to change subtitles opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

That's my css file where cue is determined. I want to create a button so that the user could change opacity & font size of the current subtitle track.

```css
    <style>
    ::cue {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      color: blue;
      background-position: right;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo elements are not selectable by any JS, but there's an actual possible (definitely not nice) solution for you:

```
<script>
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
head.appendChild(style);


// call the below function in your event handler, 
// and pass the 'style' object to it, and the required opacity:

// example: by clicking a button the opacity will be set to 0.6
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    doFormatting(style, 0.6)
});



function doFormatting(objStyle, opacity){
    if (objStyle.styleSheet){
      // maybe unnecessary, but this is required for IE8 and below.
      objStyle.styleSheet.cssText = "::cue{opacity:"+opacity+"}";
    } else {
     objStyle.innerHTML = "::cue{opacity:"+opacity+"}"
    }
}
</script>
```